# usb won't boot automatically

Tags: usb-drive

So, I haven't used a USB stick for quite a while, but as I recall, it was easy to get them to boot automatically by moving them to first priority in BIOS setup.  That's not working now.  I have a USB loaded with the latest Debian 12 installer and it boots just fine if I press F10 and select it as the boot device.  But if I press F2 ( I expect this is specific to my machine, but you get the idea ) to go into BIOS setup, and set the USB to first priority, then reboot, I get a 'no boot' message. So it will boot if specifically selected but not automatically.  I made the stick using 'dd' and it installed Debian just fine, so no issue there.  I tried using 'fdisk' to set bootable flags, but that didn't work:

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 14.94 GiB, 16043212800 bytes, 31334400 sectors
Disk model: Transcend 16GB  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x34862533

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1           0 1288191 1288192  629M  0 Empty
/dev/sdc2  *     4524   23499   18976  9.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

 Any thoughts?
```

Comment: You said BIOS but that is normally a general term people use even though they are using the newer UEFI. Given the presence of an EFI partition this is what I would assume, yet, the disk label type is `dos` and not `gpt`, could that be the reason?

Comment: Perhaps there is not one, but two options to select the USB as boot device, with one option for BIOS-style booting and the other for UEFI?

Comment: My machine is 15 years old, I don't think the UEFI is a thing back then.

Comment: Not really sure in that case. Whats going on with the start and end sectors though, shouldn't they be sequential?

Comment: That is most likely a hybrid ISO image: the range 0 - 1288191 is the ISO9660 filesystem (the main contents of the .ISO image), and 4524 - 23499 covers a UEFI ESP filesystem image included within it. In order to boot in UEFI mode when the .ISO is written to USB media, the first block of the ISO is crafted to resemble a MBR partition table unless you inspect it too closely. Within the EFI "partition", there will be a file `\BOOT\EFI\BOOTx64.efi`, so it will be UEFI-bootable. For BIOS-style boot, there should be boot code in the "MBR" that ignores the partition boot flags anyway.

Comment: In case the BIOS-style bootloader actually cares about the boot flags, the flag should probably be on `sdc1` rather than `sdc2`. The fake partition `sdc2` will be just for UEFI booting.

Comment: I don't understand a word of that ... but it sounds like the right answer ;-)